# Why doesn't NSString always display its text in Xcode debugger?

Tags: xcode, nsstring

It seems completely arbitrary, sometimes NSString will appear fine in the debugger:

```
 myStr  NSString *  0x0000000104e00040 @"Hello"
```

other times just:

```
myStr   NSString *  0x0000000104e00040
```

There's no problem with the NSStrings, just how they appear in the debugger.
Are there any factors that influence this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is a bug in the IDE I think, I don't think there's anything we can do about it.

maybe the stack depth influences that... but thats guesswork.

a `po MyStr` in the console always works fine :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also ctrl + click on an object, and choose Print Description.

[image]

Comment: ;) I bet typing po self->_text is faster and you can actually po even method calls `po [self MyMethod];`

Comment: I just wanted to share this information. If someone is focused on the keyboard, he might not know this possibility. I slightly changed my answer, because you are right speed is not the point. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

for the case where `po myString` isn't working, it might be if you're filtering console output in the IDE.
eg, i'm filtering for "myFunc" and then do `po myString`.
unless `myString` contains the string "myFunc", it doesn't show up.
this also filters out the Print Description approach mentioned above.

i would argue that this is not the best behavior on XCode's part,
and it would be better if the filter applied to only output from the program, not from the act of debugging.